# C# binary how to count how many 0 become 1

Tags: c#, count, binary, zero

In C# how can i count how many zeroes i turned to 1.

For example 
240  is 11110000. I turn it to 501 -- 0001 1111 0101.
I have turned 3 zeros to one. How can i count them.

Thank you

Comment: `x = ~old & new` gives you all the bits that were 0 and are now 1, plug it into any bit-counting code

Comment: So if you aren't turning any 1's to 0 at the same time, I would use a bitwise &. This would say something like 000111011 and you change two 0's to 1's we get 110111011 and our bitwise & would produce 110000000 and we could count the 1's in that.

Answer (score 0):

Not a very nice way but you can use this to count the changed bits

```
var ones = Convert.ToString(240 ^ 501, 2).Count(x => x == '1');
```

BTW: You can read [this](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive) for more bitwise operations